# statsmodels TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ

Tags: python, typeerror, axis, statsmodels

I'm trying to perform OLS regression using the statsmodels library.

#create design matrices as dataframe:

`y, X = dmatrices("GR ~ Im + Ct + Op + Ap + Mt", data=df, return_type='dataframe')`

#describe and fit ols model:

`model = sm.OLS(y, X)`

`results = model.fit()`

#inspect summary results:

`print(results.summary())`

Traceback:

`"TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ."`

Any insight on how to specify axis or solve the problem in another way would be much appreciated.

**Full Traceback:**

```py
Cell In[106], line 2
      1 #INSPECT summary of results
----> 2 print(results.summary())

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:2739, in RegressionResults.summary(self, yname, xname, title, alpha, slim)
   2735     top_left.append(('Covariance Type:', [self.cov_type]))
   2737 rsquared_type = '' if self.k_constant else ' (uncentered)'
   2738 top_right = [('R-squared' + rsquared_type + ':',
-> 2739               ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared]),
   2740              ('Adj. R-squared' + rsquared_type + ':',
   2741               ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared_adj]),
   2742              ('F-statistic:', ["%#8.4g" % self.fvalue]),
   2743              ('Prob (F-statistic):', ["%#6.3g" % self.f_pvalue]),
   2744              ('Log-Likelihood:', None),
   2745              ('AIC:', ["%#8.4g" % self.aic]),
   2746              ('BIC:', ["%#8.4g" % self.bic])
   2747              ]
   2749 if slim:
   2750     slimlist = ['Dep. Variable:', 'Model:', 'No. Observations:',
   2751                 'Covariance Type:', 'R-squared:', 'Adj. R-squared:',
   2752                 'F-statistic:', 'Prob (F-statistic):']

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx:36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1752, in RegressionResults.rsquared(self)
   1744 """
   1745 R-squared of the model.
   1746 
   (...)
   1749 omitted.
   1750 """
   1751 if self.k_constant:
-> 1752     return 1 - self.ssr/self.centered_tss
   1753 else:
   1754     return 1 - self.ssr/self.uncentered_tss

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/properties.pyx:36, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1702, in RegressionResults.centered_tss(self)
   1700 sigma = getattr(model, 'sigma', None)
   1701 if weights is not None:
-> 1702     mean = np.average(model.endog, weights=weights)
   1703     return np.sum(weights * (model.endog - mean)**2)
   1704 elif sigma is not None:
   1705     # Exactly matches WLS when sigma is diagonal

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in average(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:531, in average(a, axis, weights, returned, keepdims)
    529 if a.shape != wgt.shape:
    530     if axis is None:
--> 531         raise TypeError(
    532             "Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights "
    533             "differ.")
    534     if wgt.ndim != 1:
    535         raise TypeError(
    536             "1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.")

TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

Comment: That's not enough information. Show the full traceback or at least the last parts that show the location of the exception. What's the `shape` of y and X? If that is not enough to guess on the problem, then you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank for the response, Josef.

Comment: TypeError: Axis must be specified when shapes of a and weights differ.

Comment: edit your question with proper formatting of code. The comments are too painful to read.

Comment: `endog` `y` has to be 1-dimensional for OLS

Comment: y, x is a dataframe: y, X = dmatrices(dep variable ~ exp variables)

Comment: What is `model.endog.shape`? And what is `model.weights`, `model.weights.shape`?

Comment: If you are using pandas 2.0, then there might be incompatibilities with new or backwards incompatible features of pandas. In that case, what is `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Are you meaning the symmetry of y? If so, the values of the variable (y) are symmetrical or normally distributed.

Comment: ```df.dtypes``` are mostly float with some string (object) and int. The fields passing into the model are dollar values as string (dep, y) and float (ind). Does pandas require all variables to be same type?

Comment: ```model.endog.shape``` (47, 47)

Comment: ```model.weights```: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])

Comment: ```model.weights.shape```: (47, )

Comment: Changed all fields to float, except four which can only be string, and those four are not passing into the model. I'm now getting results. It appears pandas requires consistent dtypes. As a best practice, would you recommend numerical values setup as float or int for OLS?

Comment: I guess the problem was that `GR` did not have a numerical dtype and was interpreted as categorical. Then the formula transformation creates dummy variables for each unique value.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now that I've worked through the TypeError. Thanks for your time!